# Arachni gem installation error

Tags: rubygems, ubuntu-10.10, ruby-1.9.2

I am new to RoR application and i want to install arachni but when i fire "gem install arachni" it shows me error as given below

```
 /home/crystal103/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/gem:4: warning: Insecure world     writable dir /opt in PATH, mode 040777
 Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
 ERROR:  Error installing arachni:
   ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

       /home/crystal103/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb
 checking for curl/curl.h in     /opt/local/include,/opt/local/include/curl,/home/crystal103/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-           p290/include/curl,/home/crystal103/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-   p290/include,/usr/include/curl,/usr/local/include/curl... no
  need libcurl
  *** extconf.rb failed ***
  Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
  necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
  details.  You may need configuration options.

  Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/crystal103/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby


  Gem files will remain installed in /home/crystal103/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-   p290/gems/typhoeus-0.3.3 for inspection.
  Results logged to /home/crystal103/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/typhoeus-  0.3.3/ext/typhoeus/gem_make.out
```

It makes me crazy whole day but not able to solve it.... Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need libcurl with development files (include *.h) to be installed in your system.